# Themes for CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Is anyone aware of any themes in CakePHP.   I tried the CakeStrap theme and would like to look into alteratives if any, before settling on one.

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP is just a framework that creates HTML websites.  Because of that, you can use any theme you'd like from just about any source online you'd like.  I hate to say "google it", but - in this case, that's really all you need to do.

It's just HTML & CSS like any other website, so - find a theme you like, and use that.