# Cakephp and templates

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

I have been trying to Google this for quite a while and haven't been able to find any "real" answers to the question.

I am creating a website using cake and have decided to buy a template at [themeforest](http://themeforest.net).

Now most of the templates on this site is meant to be used in CMS systems. But what about Cakephp?

Is it possible to implement these layouts in cake and if so are there any restrictions? (Does all template work or only specific templates that supports some sort of feature).

Also does anyone know if there is a guide for implementing them into the cake framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems themeforest offers no specific templates for CakePHP (I searched for 'cakephp'). That means no templates work from scratch and, as you hint, you will have to adjust them to fit CakePHP.

Not knowing how well-versed you are with CakePHP layouts I suggest you take a close look at default.ctp in /app/View/Layouts. Here you can see different parts of the default CakePHP website being echoed. You would want to exchange template content with `<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>` and so on.

Depending on how specifically tailored the template is to another CMS the difficulty of re-tailoring it to CakePHP will vary. The more features tied to features in the CMS the harder it will be.

Have a look at [Introduction to layouts and theming](http://www.codeforest.net/cakephp-from-scratch-introduction-to-layouts-and-theming) and the following tutorials, [theming in real life one](http://www.codeforest.net/cakephp-from-scratch-theming-in-real-life-example-part-one) and two. Every template you want to fit to CakePHP will be different. Good Luck!

EDIT: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140757/themes-for-cakephp) question regarding CakePHP themes. The answer explains well why it is difficult to find themes/layouts/templates specific for CakePHP.

Comment: You said "Themeforest" doesnt offer any specific templates for CakePHP. Do you know any sites that does?

Comment: Please see the edition I made. I could find nothing similar to a template website. [These](http://cakephp.seesaa.net/article/20355864.html) hardly qualify. I downloaded contented1 and it looks Cake-ish but is probably only usable as inspirational code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're so eagerly looking for themes for CakePHP, but you know that CakePHP is not a CMS but a framework?

Comment: @burzum Themes saves alot of time for a backend guy like me :)